# Recursive code that returns the sums of an array that match a target

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, sum, find

the following code shows all the possible sums equal to a target in an array, my problem is that I understand the logic of how it works in the first answer, however I do not understand how recursion works so that the card is the same again and check more results (more arrays) and in the same way as the combination array is "cleaned" if it does this after recursive operations, try desktop tests and chatGPT but I simply cannot understand how it works in your whole.

```
function findSums(nums, target) {
    function findSum(target, start, combination) {
        
        if (target === 0) {
            result.push([...combination]);
            return;
        }
        for (let i = start; i < nums.length; i++) {
            console.log('i: ',i,'start: ',start,'n1:',nums[i],'n2:',nums[i-1]);

            if (i > start && nums[i] === nums[i - 1]) {                
                continue;
            }
            findSum(target - nums[i], i + 1, combination);
            combination.pop();
        }
    }
    nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let start = 0;
    let combination = [];
    let result = [];
    findSum(target, start, combination);
    return result;
}
console.log(findSums([1, 3, 2, 4, 5], 6));
```

I would like you to help me understand how this code works. I think my biggest confusion lies in the recursive call within the for, and I also don't understand why at a certain point "i" becomes different from "start"

Comment: I don't think this code works. The output is a bunch of empty arrays, which makes sense because none of the code adds elements to the `combination` array at any point. I think you're missing `combination.push(nums[i]);` before recursing. Please [edit] the post to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

let me try to help you understand the code by breaking it down in step by step especially the recusrion part:

The `findSums` function is basically made to find all unique combinations of numbers in the `nums` array that add up to a given `target`. It does this by using a helper function `findSum` which is defined inside `findSums`.

Here's what the `findSum` function actually does is:

**Base Case**: If the `target` is 0, it means the current `combination` of numbers adds up to the original `target`. This combination is then added to the `result` array, and the function returns.

**Recursive Case**: The function iterates over the `nums` array starting from the `start` index. For each number at index `i`, it checks if this number can be part of a combination that adds up to the `target`.

**Avoiding Duplication**: If the current number is the same as the previous number and `i` is greater than `start`, it skips this number to avoid duplicate combinations.

**Recursive Call**: It makes a recursive call to `findSum` with the new target `(target - nums[i])`, the new start index `(i + 1)`, and the current combination of numbers.

**Backtracking**: After the recursive call, it removes the last number added to the `combination` by calling `combination.pop()`. This is the backtracking step that allows the function to try different combinations.

I hope you understood what `findSum` function is actually doing here :)
Now let me answer some of your specific questions:

***1. How does recursion work so that the card is the same again and check more results (more arrays)?***

Recursion actually works by calling the same function with different parameters. In this case, the `findSum` function is called with a reduced target and an incremented start index. Each recursive call is independent of others and has its own execution context. This means that the `combination` array and other variables are unique to each call.

***2. How is the combination array "cleaned" if it does this after recursive operations?***

The combination array is "cleaned" by the `combination.pop()` operation. This happens after the recursive call returns. It removes the last element that was added before the recursive call, effectively undoing the last step and allowing the loop to try the next number.

***3. Why at a certain point "i" becomes different from "start"?***

The variable `i` becomes different from `start` because `start` is the index from which the function should start considering numbers in the `nums` array, while `i` is the current index in the loop. As the loop progresses, `i` increments, but `start` remains the same until the next recursive call, where it is set to `i + 1`. This ensures that each combination uses different elements and avoids reusing the same element.

**Here is an example with the input `[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]` and `target` 6:**

Sort the array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Start with an empty combination `[]` and `start` at 0.

Try adding `1` to the combination and call `findSum(5, 1, [1])`.

In the new call, try adding `2` to the combination and call `findSum(3, 2, [1, 2])`.

In the new call, try adding `3` to the combination and call `findSum(0, 3, [1, 2, 3])`.

Since the target is now 0, add `[1, 2, 3]` to the result and return.
Backtrack by popping `3` from the combination and try the next number.
Continue this process until all combinations are tried.

Each recursive call explores a different path in the search space, and backtracking ensures that all possible combinations are considered. The `start` parameter is crucial for avoiding duplicates and ensuring that each combination is unique.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).